# form not rendering correctly in modal

Tags: html, symfony, modal-dialog, twig

I try to render a form with ajax and show it in a modal.
But the fom tags in the modal just appears next to eachother when i check the source code in my browser. How can I resolve this?

Here is my written code of the modal in:

```
<!-- Modal Edit client -->
<div id="editClient" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Client</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="editClientForm" action="{{ path('client_details') }}" method="POST">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save changes">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal opens with the form fields and closes when cancel is clicked.

Here is the source code from the browser:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="editClientForm" action="/ruben/avr_symfony/web/app_dev.php/configurator/client/details" method="POST"></form>
    => here comes all the form fields and buttons.
</div>
```

As you can see, it closes the form tag before putting in the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I hade a  closing table tag wich i typed as < table > instead of < / table > in my code above the modal code.

This solved the issue.